# javascript counter with if else

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a counter, that can only go from 0, to a max of 10, right now I can add and delete number from the counter, but for some reason my if/else never works, no matter where I put them. I'm a real noob to javascript so if anyone could give me some advice it would be highly appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = 0;
if (clicks < 0) {
    clicks = 0;
    document.getElementById("ticketAmmount").innerHTML = clicks;
}
function onClick() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("ticketAmmount").innerHTML = clicks;
};
function offClick() {
    clicks -= 1;
    document.getElementById("ticketAmmount").innerHTML = clicks;
}
```

i also have tried this: but then the counter gives me NaN

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = 0;

function onClick() {
if (clicks < 0) {
    clicks = 0;
    document.getElementById("ticketAmmount").innerHTML = clicks;
} else {
 clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("ticketAmmount").innerHTML = clicks;
}

};
function offClick() {
    clicks -= 1;
    document.getElementById("ticketAmmount").innerHTML = clicks;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you check if `clicks < 0` right after setting it to `0`?

Comment: where is the `if/else`?

Comment: If the `if` statement you're showing in the code block is any indication of where you're trying to put your `if/else` blocks, they'll only ever run once. You need to put them in your functions if you want them to run more than once.

Comment: i thought that everytime you hit the button, the script reads it from bottom to top, so if the clicks is smaller then 0, it should reset the counter back to 0 instead of going to -1

Comment: So add the if check inside of the in/off clicks

Comment: Well, logically, you would probably want to check if `clicks < 0` after decrementing it, so in the `offClick` function, and have the `clicks > 10` check after the increment in the `onClick` function.

Comment: your code is working fine check here http://jsfiddle.net/x49hquck/ then what is your problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost right, put your `if` within your onClick and offClick functions, and remove the first one (that doesn't seem useful):

```
var clicks = 0;

document.getElementById("ticketAmmount").innerHTML = clicks;

function onClick() {
    clicks += 1;
    if (clicks > 10) {
        clicks = 10;
    }
    document.getElementById("ticketAmmount").innerHTML = clicks;
};
function offClick() {
    clicks -= 1;
    if (clicks < 0) {
        clicks = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("ticketAmmount").innerHTML = clicks;
}
```

Comment: Yes it works thanks! It's actually really logic when you think about it!

Answer (score 2):

It's not very complicated:

```js
var minVal = 0, maxVal = 10, clicks = 0,
    display = document.getElementById("ticketAmmount");

function countUp(){
  clicks = Math.min( maxVal, clicks+1 );
  display.innerHTML = clicks;
}

function countDown(){
  clicks = Math.max( minVal, clicks-1 );
  display.innerHTML = clicks;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="countDown();">-</button>
<span id="ticketAmmount">0</span>
<button onclick="countUp();">+</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`if (clicks < 0)` is being called only once, when the page loads, and right after you set `clicks = 0`, so it never meets the criteria.  You need to put that logic in both the `onClick` and `offClick` or extract it out in to some method, for example:

```
var clicks = 0;
function resetClicks() {
    if (clicks < 0) {
      clicks = 0;
      document.getElementById("ticketAmmount").innerHTML = clicks;
    }
}

function onClick() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("ticketAmmount").innerHTML = clicks;
    resetClicks();
};
function offClick() {
    clicks -= 1;
    document.getElementById("ticketAmmount").innerHTML = clicks;
    resetClicks();
}
```